# Is it possible to print with Chinese characters using Linux Cups Server?

Tags: linux, cups, printer

We have printer installed and configured in CUPS server. It is registered in Oracle apps and when we print any report in English language from Oracle apps it is printing correctly.

When we try to print the same report, but with Chinese characters it is not printing, but gets stuck-up in the print queue.

Can you please help me in this regard? What do we need to do to configure it properly?

Answer (score 0):

Answer for the above questions is Yes, We can print Chinese Characters in report output using Oracle Pasta printer drivers.

Pasta Drivers will convert your actual report output using XML publisher.